# Java spring junit writing tests that persist data

Tags: java, spring, junit4

I have written tests in the past using in memory databses.

What i wanted to know was is it possible to write tests in spring, junit, java, using in memory DB and the data is not rolledback after each test but kept in the db.

Basically whereby the tests are dependant on each other?

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rollbacking db changes or not is up to you.

But unit test should be independent from each other.

Small extract from a recent [DZone article](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/unit-testing-best-practices) on the subject:

> Make each test independent to all the others
>
> Do not make chain of unit test cases. It will prevent you to identify the root cause of test case failures and you will have to
> debug the code. Also, it creates dependency, means if you have to
> change one test case then you need to make changes in multiple
> testcases unnecessarily.
>
> Try to use @Before and @After methods to setup per-requisites if any for all your test cases. If you need to multiple things to support
> different test cases in @Before or @After, then consider creating new
> Test class.

Answer (score 1):

Your tests should be independent.

But if you want I guess you can try the @Rollback annotation.

I have not tried but have seen in the doc spec while doing transactions.